# Блок поверх slick slider'a

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть слайдер, реализованный с помощью плагина "slick slider".

Суть в том, что у его обертки стоит свойство overflow:hidden для того, чтобы слайды не вылазили за видимую область.

Нужно сделать всплывающий блок, при наведении на ссылку в слайде. 
Сейчас этот блок вылазит за обёртку слайдера, обрезаясь по краям, что не есть хорошо.

Как это можно лучше реализовать? Может тут кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей, используя slick slider?

Comment: Приложите ваш сверстанный слайдер, чтобы было видно на что ориентироваться

Comment: Как тут добавить библиотеку slick slider'а?

Comment: "Фрагмент кода... " - "Добавить внешнюю библиотеку"

Comment: Существует 3 варианта решения вашей проблемы, первый - задать "обертке" принудительно `overflow-y: auto`. второй - задать отступы у слайдов, если обрезается небольшая часть всплывающего окна. третий - использовать `position: fixed` для уведомления. Примеры будут если прикрутите код слайдера в вопрос.

Comment: спасибо, вашего ответа уже более чем достаточно.

Answer (score -1):

Добавляй блок вне slick слайдера, координаты позиционирования высчитывай на js

Comment: А как их высчитать, если позиция слайда на странице меняется, в зависимости от разрешения?

Comment: window.onresize, извини, не могу дать пример кода так как сейчас с телефона, но куда копать инфу я дал, это гуглится за 5 минут и еще за 5 — реализуется